# CMake: include_external_msproject() and mapping configurations

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a MSVC++ project *fooproj* that basically comes as input to the project I'm working on.  I want to use CMake to add some sanity to the work on configuration of the solution+projects.  Furthermore, I will be making changes (and contributing them back) in *fooproj* so I'd really like to properly import it into the solution that CMake generates so I'm looking at using include_external_msproject(), but I'd like to somehow control which configuration of *fooproj* I use for Debug/Release:

- solution-lvl Debug -> project-lvl LibDebug
- solution-lvl Release -> project-lvl LibRelease

Currently I do this manually after regenerating the solution using the *Configuration Manager* in VS, but I'd like to make it automatic.  Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this exact same issue while I port all our projects to use CMake.

A project I am importing has spaces in the configuration (Release md), and I am trying to map it to a solution config (Release_md), which is not possible I don't think.

As far as my researching has gone, there isn't any actual support for mapping the solution configurations to project configurations manually, since the CMake configurations are very nearly hardcoded to be 1:1 in Visual Studio. Different projects (that aren't imported as external ms projects) cannot have differing/less/more configs from the specified solution/CMake configuration.

I don't know about your case with *fooproj* specifically, but couldn't you add the **Release** and **Debug** configs to *fooproj* to match the solution configs from CMake?

Edit: Maybe [this email thread](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-April/036388.html) can potentially help you?  It mentions something about converting the external project to an imported target and mapping it that way.

Comment: *Release* and *Debug* already exist in the project and I'm adding the other two project configs in order to not disturb other's work.